# Extract rtsp url from an html file bash

Tags: html, string, bash, url, rtsp

i am newbie in bash and i want to extract an rtsp url of an html file (like substring does), the rtsp address is inside the file like this:

```
"rtsp://www.address.com:9843/blablabla/blablabla@3134"
```

Any ideas? thank you very much.

Comment: What do you have? What do you want? Why do you think bash is the right tool? Can you give an example?

Comment: I have a file.html and i want it in any script or program languaje wich can be executed from a terminal because i want to put it in a server. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please rewrite your question with all the needed details for a helpful answer. Please describe your problem precisely or add a small example input file together with the expected output. Please also give a bit of context: Where does the file come from, why does the server need the url, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, because of the very vague question:

```
perl -wne 'print $& if /"rtsp:.*?"/' file.html
```